# Android Chrome Browser casting to Chromecast - if I unplug chromecast (or unplug network), then the Chrome Browser page crashes

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-chrome, android-cast-api

I have replicated the issue on Chrome and Edge (on Android). Although don't appear to have the issue on Chrome and Edge (Windows). I have tried Chrome v83 and latest v98.0.4758.101 - same issue. I can successfully cast and disconnect.

However, if the network drops, router powers off, wifi unit powers off, cast receiver is unplugged - then the browser window on the Android also crashes (closes). We have included further debugging, android debugging, usb debuggin but there is no evidence of why the browser is crashing / closing.

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

We use Google Chromecast session.sendMessage to communicate from our web app to our casted web app.
I found when there was a network issue on an Android device using google chrome, calling session.sendMessage would crash Chrome.
No errors or events received the webrowser would just exit.

There were 3 separate instances;
Internet outage,
chromeCast powered off,
wifi was turned off.

The workaround was to run some basic checks before sending a message to the API.

The casting session is alive
The status of navigator.onLine is true
and a simple network check (API Call) == 200

all 3 checks must pass before sending a message.
If one or more checks failed kill the session.

This does result in slightly slower cast speeds.